# How do I set the title for a dialog in jQuery dynamically?

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic, dialog, title

```
<div class="lessonDetails">
        <a href="#popUpLink" class="popUpLink">Lesson Details</a>
        <div class="popUpDialog" title="Lesson Details">
        <p>This is lesson dialog </p>
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="courseDetails">
    <a href="#popUpLink" class="popUpLink">Course Timetable and Resources</a>
    <div class="popUpDialog" title="Course Timetable and Resources">
        <p>Course Timetable</p>
        <p>Resources</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

​

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.popUpLink').each(function() {
        $.data(this, 'dialog', $(this).next('.popUpDialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            title: 'Info',
            draggable: true
        }));
    }).click(function() {
        $.data(this, 'dialog').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
});​
```

How do I set the title of the dialog such that the first dialog (lesson dialog) will have the title of "**Lesson Details**" and second dialog (course dialog) will be "**Course Timetable and Resources**"?

Bearing in mind the amount of dialogs there are is dynamically decided in the back-end.

Comment: so... you have trouble reading `title` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change this

```
 title: 'Info',
```

to this

```
title: $(this).html(),
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N8BEH/)